# Is there a way to get count of units of a specific product present in the cart?(Spree rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I can't seem to find a way to get count of a specific product that's added in cart.

I've tried `simple_current_order.item_count` but it provides the count of whole cart items.

I expect it to be some method `count_quantity_in_cart(@product)` which returns an `integer` as a result

Answer (score 0):

To get count of units for a specific product present in the cart.

```
simple_current_order.where(product: @product).to_a.sum(&:quantity)
```